# python matplotlib: plot.savefig distorts table column

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I analyzed a guessing game for lift usage on a mountain and plotted those things per day. In the plot window, it looks the way I want it to look but when saving as a png, it squeezes the first column.

I have no idea why this happens. Does anyone have any idea? When saving from plot it doesn't do this.

[correct depiction in plot window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqNkJ.png)

[squeezed first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp3hZ.png)

Code for the plot looks like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8), dpi=80, facecolor = 'white')

# Histogram
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid( (1,3),(0,0), colspan = 2)
plt.hist(estDay.visitors[estDay.date == est_date], color='#E7E7E7', bins=15)
plt.axvline(estDay.visitors[estDay.date == est_date].mean(), linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3, color='#353535')
plt.axvline(erst.eintritte[erst.date == est_date].mean(), linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3, color='#AF272F')
plt.title(est_date)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
summ = statSumm(est_date)

# Info Table
plt.subplot2grid( (1,3),(0,2))
plt.axis('off')
plt.table( cellText = summ.values,
           rowLabels = summ.index,
           colLabels = summ.columns, 
           cellLoc = 'center', 
           rowLoc = 'center', 
           bbox=[0.6, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8] )

plt.savefig('lottoDays/' + est_date + '.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea would be to draw the canvas once before saving such that the row has the chance to adapt its size to the row headers.

```
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry for the post. am just starting with python.